# How to add calculated values to existing column in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame (file), which has two columns:

```
Path length: 0.5; 0.5; NA; 5; NA; 8; NA
Global efficiency: NA; NA; 0.8; 0.2; 0.3; NA; NA
```

Now I want to convert the global efficiency values into path length values by: `path length = 1 / global efficiency`. I want to do this ONLY if the path length value = NA. Then I want to add the calculated path lengths to the existing column 'path length'. Any help how to do that?

I already did:

```
  ifelse(file$P_L_Mean != 'NA')
    {
    file$P_L_Mean <- 1/file$P_Eglob_Mean
    }
```

But this does not add the values to the existing column...

Thanks!

Comment: The names in the code and in the data.frame is not matching.  Which one is correct ?

Comment: I see the != should be ==

Comment: The names in the code are correct. I just wrote the dataframe in a simplified version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a logical index with `is.na` and assign

```
i1 <- is.na(file$P_L_Mean)
file$P_L_Mean[i1] <- 1/file$P_Eglob_Mean[i1]
```

---

We can also do this with `ifelse`

```
file$P_L_Mean <- with(file, ifelse(is.na(P_L_Mean), 1/P_Eglob_Mean, P_L_Mean))
```

Comment: Thanks! One more question: for the 2nd solution: why do you need to include 'P_L_Mean' at the end?

Comment: @user222905  If you look at the `?ifelse`, there are three arguments -`test`, 'yes', 'no' where `test` takes a logical index, 'yes' takes values if the condition in 'test' satisfies and 'no' takes values if the 'test' is not satisfied.  Essentially, here we are passing all 3 arguments with the same length ie. the whole column.  It replaces based on the 'test' condition

Comment: Ah, so when test = true (so, P_L_Mean = NA), r will fill in 1/P_Eglob_Mean and when test = false, it will return just the P_L_Mean value, right. I Understand!

Answer (score 1):

```
X=data.frame(path_length=c(0.5,0.5,NA,5,NA,8),global_eff=c(NA,NA,0.8,0.2,0.3,NA))

fun=Vectorize(function(x,y){if (is.na(x)){return(1/y)}})
X= X %>% mutate(global_eff_2=fun(path_length,global_eff))
```